# Removing Pod from project - xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I'm trying to remove pod from my project. After i'm deleting all the files and everything i'm getting this messages

```
diff: /../Podfile.lock: No such file or directory
diff: /Manifest.lock: No such file or directory
error: The sandbox is not in sync with the Podfile.lock. Run 'pod install' or update your CocoaPods installation.
```

I tried to remove the pods from the project, reinstall them, remove the script from the build phase, nothing is working.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Ok, I fixed it.

Just use this tool https://github.com/kylef/cocoapods-deintegrate and now everything works fine!

Answer (score 40):

remove the pod from the pod file then reinstall pods

open terminal and type

```
cd ~/projectDirectoryPath
```

then type

```
open -a Xcode Podfile
```

this will open up the podfile

delete the line

```
 pod 'Alamofire'
```

then save the file (Alamofire is just an example)

in the terminal type

```
pod install
```

and this should update the project and remove the unwanted pod file..

Answer (score 6):

Just to simplify what Aviv mentioned, if you want to completely remove all traces of any pods from a project then just delete all of the pod related files from your project folder and run:

```
sudo gem install cocoapods-deintegrate

pod deintegrate
```

And the sandbox Podfile.lock error should go away.

Comment: thanks ninja...simple is good

Answer (score 0):

Removing Pod from project

open terminal and run these scripts

```
$ pod deintegrate
$ pod clean
$ rm Podfile
```

last but not lease,

```
remove the projectFile.xcworkspace from the project
```