# Removing SwiftyJSON framework/cocoapod from Xcode project

Tags: swift, xcode, parsing, cocoapods, swifty-json

My already finished app has come up with a few warnings after the Swift 4.0 language came out. It says SwiftyJSON is deprecated. After some research Ive found that SwiftyJSON is deprecated probably due to the new easy method of parsing JSON.
My goal now is to implement this new method to avoid problems in the future.

So my question is, Is there a way to remove all SwiftyJSON framework/cocoapods from my project and be able to work from the Xcode project as opposed to the Xcworkspace? So I can work on the new method of parsing JSON?

Comment: remove pod swiftly line from your Podfile, then do a pod install from terminal

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing Pod from project - xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30116595/removing-pod-from-project-xcode)

Comment: https://github.com/CocoaPods/cocoapods-deintegrate

Answer (score 1):

Run `pod update SwiftyJSON` command

It will update the SwiftyJSON to it's latest version 4.0.0 which has the Swift 4 compatibility.

Hope it helps.

Comment: This doesn't answer the original question. The OP was trying to remove the SwiftyJSON pod and associated files not updating or getting rid of warnings.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do (as you are using cocoapods) is to open the file Podfile, which contains the list of your pods and remove the line that says `pod 'SwiftyJSON'` and then run `pod install` in the terminal from your project root folder. This will remove it.

Actually there is SwiftyJSON 4. I believe only SwiftyJSON 3 is deprecated.